# How to display images stored in a virtual directory in .NET Core app?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

I want to display images on my .net core website. The images are stored outside of the website-folder on an IIS server.

On the internet, I read that one way to go about doing so, is using a virtual directory which I then set up. Below the configuration of the virtual directory:

[image: Configuration of the virtual directory]

I thought, it would be easy to access pictures saved inside of the folder, the virtual directory points to, but I've not succeeded until now.

In my html, I tried the following:

```
<img src="/Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

and

```
<img src="Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

and

```
<img src="../Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

and

```
<img src="./Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

but nothing worked.
When inspecting the website, there's an 404 error for the image.

**Update:** I added permissions to the virtual directory (full access) for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS

**Update**: So it seems as if I cannot access virtual directories from a .net core web app as per this blog post: https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/

Instead, the author advises to use `UseFileServer()` in `Startup.cs`. I'm, however, not sure yet how to upload images into the file server and display them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out you cannot use virtual directories in ASP.NET Core web applications (as per this blog post, for instance: https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/ ). 
Instead of configuring a virtual directory pointing to a certain folder on your server, you have to add the following code to your `Configure()` in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\server\path"),
RequestPath = new PathString("/MyPath"),
EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
});
```

If the the path would, for example point to a folder containg the image image.jpg, you could use the image from your code like this:

```
<img src="/MyPath/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the image path as below.

```
<img src="./test/1.jpg"/>
```

[image]

[image]

check that you give right permission to the image folder.

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it's not working yet. I also just gave full access to IIS_USRS and IUSR to the virtual directory. In google chrome there's the following error for the image: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Does the virtual directory have to be converted to application?

Comment: Could you share your virtual directory full path and your site page path? try to clear the cache and history and cache of the browser. if your site page is under subfolder you need to set  <img src="../test/1.jpg" alt="loading"/> [sitefolder](https://imgur.com/a/uZcPMpV) and [virtual dir path](https://imgur.com/a/MfC5IRd)

Comment: share snapshot of the error and refresh or restart iis server.

Comment: i tried using incognito mode (instead of clearing cache and history) and used the command `iisreset` on the hosting server. Error persists tho. Here are snapshots of the sitefolder, virtual dir path etc: https://imgur.com/a/e9XeTzH . thanks a lot for your help

Comment: are you using asp.net application? if yes than you need to publish your site or application after changing the file. you see the [image](https://imgur.com/a/nhTqgFJ) your file is still using <img src="Uploads/image.jpg" /> instead of   <img src="./test/1.jpg" alt="loading"/>

Comment: yes, I'm using an asp.net app. I guess the reason why it was <img src="Uploads/image.jpg"/> instead of <img src="./Uploads/imgage.jpg" alt="loading" /> is that I was trying out different things. Now, I changed it back to <img src="./Uploads/image.jpg" alt="loading" />, published it again, changed the publish file on the host server and restarted iis. Here you can see that I changed it back again: https://imgur.com/a/Y74W2a8 . thanks again:)

Comment: is your page is under the subfolder of the site?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you meant by page, but the virtual directory is a direct subfolder of the main website. Or what page were you talking about?

Comment: I've just noticed that everything works perfectly when I try the same thing with the default web site (the one thats like an example site: https://imgur.com/a/DanaUS4). But when I do the same thing with my actual website, it does not work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195242/discussion-between-jalpa-panchal-and-jimmy).

Comment: your image page is under the site subfolder or site root folder?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzTKa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Configure` method, apply the below code.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "uploads")),
    RequestPath = "/uploads"
});
```